# Webkit Develop Inspektor show long strings

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit, google-chrome

When i debug javascript in webkit browser(f.e. Safari), often i have some string variables and value of these variables are often very long, webkit make it shorter with "..." at the end, but i want to see all value of this variables, how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know all texts are truncated only when being listed as property of an object. If you're logging a text variable directly, it should show the whole text.

```
var foo = {bar:Array(1000).join('baz')};
console.log(foo); // this will truncate value of foo.bar
console.log(foo.bar); // this should show the whole text
```

If you still want to change the limit, here is my quick solution.
It may not be the best way to do this, but if you can find a JS file responsible for Dev tools (for my Google Chrome installation the file is DevTools.js, for Safari 5 - InjectedScript.js), open it in a text editor, look for the function InjectedScript._describe. Inside this function you will find

```
if (obj.length > 100)
   return "\"" + obj.substring(0, 100) + "\u2026\"";
```

increase the limit from 100 to sth else or remove both lines.

Comment: Where is the location of  DevTools.js in Microsoft Windows8?

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered that the Chrome dev tools has a `copy` function which copies to clipboard - without truncation! Handily it also serializes objects to JSON and DOM elements to HTML, straight to the clipboard.

```
copy(someLongString); // no truncation!
copy({ foo : true }); // JSON
copy(someDOMElement); // HTML
```

Since I was trying to copy a long string to clipboard for analysis elsewhere, this served my needs perfectly