# How to watch a string in Google developer Tools

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I try to debug some javascript code with Node-inspector and google developer tools but when try to watch string i cant see all the string like below image it show some first part of string and trim the other part and only show length of string.but i want to see full length of string.

[image: Cant see all part of string]

and in the scope variable pane [image: Scope Variable Pane]

I can't expand the string and only can double click on it but when double click 
on string the string is equal that in main window.

and when use `console.log` i cant see the full length of string :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On the right column expand the list called "scope variables" where you have a better view of every value.

Comment: also in scope variables i cant see all the string.the string is equal to i see in main window

Comment: @MBehtemam Click on the string to expand it.

Comment: I am afraid that your string is actually what you see there. I mean, it might be that your string ends with "... (length 194)". I'm saying that because in the past, using the procedure above, I have been able to read strings much longer than yours!

Comment: @mastazi i try with another string with 1000 charachter but every thing is same as before and i cant see full length of string

Answer (score 2):

Try the following answer:

[Webkit Develop Inspektor show long strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165987/webkit-develop-inspektor-show-long-strings/3171646#3171646)

You could also use `Node Inspector` which is quite similar to Google DevTools. The latest version (from master) has a limit of 10 000 characters. [See this link](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/201).

Comment: I cant find DevTools.js file

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the `mdx.toString()` in Console Tab/View ?

Comment: what does this object represent ?